# Force measurement when pulling on a rope

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics

Last week my high-school physics teacher presented us with a task that went as follows (it was posed in German, so I’ll translate here):

“Two people pull on opposing sides of a rope. Each person exerts a force of $100\,\text{N}$. If we exchange one person for a static wall, the wall will exert the same $100\,\text{N}$ as the person did before (Newton’s third law). How much force does the rope have to withstand? Have your teacher show you by cutting the rope in half and adding a spring force gauge (German: ‘Federkraftmesser’) in the centre.”

Now, I’m not particularly happy about the phrasing of this question (in German it was: “Welche Kraft muss das Seil aushalten?”), because it doesn’t really tell me what I’m supposed to do, but here are my thoughts:

1. The rope isn’t moving, i.e. its velocity isn’t changing, so the net force acting upon the rope must be zero. This makes sense, considering $\vec{F}_{12} = -\vec{F}_{21}$, so that the sum of the forces can be $0$: $\vec{F}_{12} + \vec{F}_{21} = 0$.
2. Considering a different approach, “withstand” may also mean that the rope is strong enough not to tear. Seeing it that way, I believe I would have to add not the force vectors, but their absolute values, because each side is pulling with a force of $100\,\text{N}$. That way, for the rope to not tear, it would have to withstand at least $\left| \vec{F}_{12}\right| + \left| \vec{F}_{21}\right| = 100\,\text{N} + 100\,\text{N} = 200\,\text{N}$.

However, the solution to the question said that the correct answer is $100\,\text{N}$, and that makes no sense to me whatsoever. We actually did the experiment that was posed in the question, too, just with weaker forces. We used $1.5\,\text{N}$ on each side, then cut the rope and added another spring force gauge in the centre, and sure enough the one in the centre also showed $1.5\,\text{N}$. I can see why it wouldn’t show $0$, obviously something *is* pulling on it, but even seeing it with my own two eyes, it makes no sense to me that the gauge in the centre would show $1.5\,\text{N}$ and not $3\,\text{N}$.

Is there anything I’m missing here or some mathematical explanation that can clear up my confusion?